# How can I pass multiple errors down a ReplaySubject?

Tags: c#, error-handling, system.reactive

How can I pass multiple errors down a `ReplaySubject`?

When I call `OnError` only the first exception is passed. I need to call on multiple times and have all  `errors/exceptions` passed.

I see internally `RX` creates a `AnonymousSafeObserver` and `OnError` is calling the `Dispose`.

Can i create my own version of `AnonymousSafeObserver` some how to change the functionality?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must not send multiple errors into an Rx stream. It is a fundamental property of Rx that Observables exhibit the following grammar:

```
OnNext*(OnError|OnCompleted)?
```

That is, a stream consists of zero or more `OnNext` events followed optionally by a single `OnError` or `OnCompleted`.

The `AnonymousSafeObserver` is merely enforcing this invariant.

It sounds like your errors are in fact *data* of the stream rather than a signal that the stream itself has terminated exceptionally. In such a case create a type to carry this data and send that through `OnNext` instead.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can call `.Materialize()` on an observable to turn it from `IObservable<T>` to `IObservable<Notification<T>>`. This allows the standard `.OnError(...)` call to be sent as an `.OnNext(...)`, which can then allow multiple `.OnError(...)` calls to be present in complex observables (such as those created with `.Merge()`). While it won't let a single observable return multiple errors, it will let multiple errors to be propagated on a carefully crafted observable.